# Custom badges on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, support, badges

My question is can new badges be added or removed from the already list of existing badges?

Comment: Can you mention some of the badges that aren't in Ask Ubuntu? I have a feeling you are talking about the tag badges...

Comment: k srry... it was for a badge for 200 rep in one day .. i had seen it on chem.SE ..didnt know it was added to all SE sites.. edited my question

Comment: We'd need more context as to what badges you'd be looking for, without the details we can't know what you're after.

Answer (score 10):

Nice ideas would be:

**Does not have a life Badge** - Awarded for 200 consecutive days

**Forever Alone Badge** - Awarded for 365 consecutive days and no girlfriend detected over that period.

**Keep on Rolling Badge** - Gain 100+ points every day for 1 week.

**Sonic de Hedgehog Badge** - Gain 100+ points every day for 1 month

**Trololol** - Have 3x more comments than all of your questions and answers combined

**Wololo** - Have so many comments that people will convert to commentisim.

**Space Balls Power** - Answer a question every 42 days.

Comment: Hmm.  Joking aside, it looks like you're assuming AU users are all unmarried heterosexual males.  Other than that, the 100+ badge ideas are interesting....  Funny otherwise.

Comment: what is the speciality of 42?

Comment: 42 IS the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life the Universe and Everything

Comment: @tachyons Read *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.

Comment: +1 for the humour. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A few (crappy) ideas are:

- **Optimist** – Has made at least 150 votes and none are downvotes.
- **Street-cleaner** – Has at least 10 flags and less than 20 votes.
- **Socially accepted** – Has 5 accepted answers in a row.
- **Pessimist** – Has made at least 150 votes and over half are downvotes.

Comment: I like 'optimist'.  Heh.

Comment: Also add: **Dumpster-diver**-Over half of activity on old questions(At least 50 actions required)

Comment: @belacqua I would've got that already

Answer (score 3):

## Unlucky

Asked a question with 5k views within one month, but no upvotes.

Note: this badge may help to detect ignored but important questions.

Comment: i consider this as an impossible scenario

Comment: If then ,this must be a gold badge :D

Answer (score -1):

**Everyday Vist & Minimum 10 Reputation on everyday**  for **a month**  => A Silver Badge .

**Everyday Vist & Minimum 10 Reputation on everyday**  for **a year**  => A Gold Badge .