# New Badge feature

Tags: feature-request

Hi I am here with a new badge feature .

Suppose A person visits everyday and gaining minimum 10 reputation every day for one month => A Silver Badge .

Similarly Visiting everyday and gain minimum 10 reputation everyday and up to an Year 
=> A Gold Badge .

Comment: There are already badges for visiting every day for some time span, even without rep gain: [Enthusiast](http://askubuntu.com/badges/52/enthusiast) and [Fanatic](http://askubuntu.com/badges/53/fanatic).

Comment: You can post your Idea [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3090/custom-badges-on-ask-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that this might breed some engagement, I think it would lead to more poor answers.  One upvote is relatively easy to achieve with a poor answer.

Comment: +1 for this poor answer. Just kidding! I actually agree.

Comment: I can only award humour stars in chat.

Comment: Heh.  Well, I tend to avoid chat, as I tend to get stuck there in that happy limbo.

Comment: If that's the case, you should really try to teach users not to upvote poor answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's already reputation badges.  IMO this would take too much settings and configuration.  if anything, the first one about a month could be bronze, 10 rep every day for a year could be silver.  if it were 50 rep a day for a year then maybe gold, but nobody ever would get this.